# How to convert boolean(True/False) in RF to boolean(true/false) in Json

Tags: json, boolean, robotframework

I'm post one request in Robotfamework, one field only receive true/false from API, not True/False, but True/False is boolean in RF. How to convert from True/False to true/false?

True/False is boolean in RF, but API needs true/false

Here is the post request body needed from API

```
{
    "id": 123456,
    "name": "test",
    "isActive": false
}
```

However, I only can provide the following post request body

```
{
    "id": 123456,
    "name": "test",
    "isActive": False
}
```

Comment: Try `${True}` and `${False}` instead.

Comment: This can't solve this issue. We will get True/False if we use ${True}/${False}, not true/false

Answer (score 1):

Use json library to do that

```
*** Settings ***
Library  json

*** Test Cases ***
TC1
    &{POST_DICTIONARY}=  Create Dictionary  name=Clef  employed=${False}
    ${JSON_STRING}=  json.dumps  ${POST_DICTIONARY} 
    Log To Console  ${JSON_STRING}
    Log  ${JSON_STRING}
```

Output in console will be

```
TC1    ..{"name": "Clef", "employed": false}
TC1    | PASS |
```

In log.html,
[image]

Instead of output of `json.dumps`, if we log `${POST_DICTIONARY}`, we will see this

```
{'name': 'Clef', 'employed': False}
```

because we are logging python dictionary and the boolean will be `False` in python.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had this problem earlier as well. I tackled it by doing the following with the `json` library.

In the settings area of the robot test:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  json
Library  String
Library  Collections
```

First we create a dictionary, then we dump it into a String, finally replace the wrong false type into the wanted `false`.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test custom false
  &{POST_DICTIONARY}=  Create Dictionary  name=John  employed=false
  ${JSON_STRING}=  json.dumps  ${POST_DICTIONARY}
  ${JSON_STRING}=  Replace String  ${JSON_STRING}  "false"  false
  Log To Console  ${JSON_STRING}
```

The resultant `${JSON_STRING}` will now look like this:

```
{"name": "John", "employed": false}
```

Comment: `employed=false`; here false is treated as string. So after json dumps, the json will have double quotes around false.

Instead if we do `employed=${False}`, the output of `${False}` will be treated as boolean. So after json dumps, the json will not have double quotes around false. And we do not need to use Replace String.